# How to search after string in PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem with logic about PHP search. So I have tried as much as I can but still not found any answer. My problem was that I want to search the date Arrive "Sun, May 31, 2015" and Depart "Tue, June 09, 2015" from the text below.

Example

```
 "2 Guests Arrive Sun, May 31, 2015 Depart Tue, June 09, 2015 View itinerary"
```

Could anyone give me the example and better with explanation or link to view more detail?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit this link. [Find date in string: Function to find a date in a string using Regular Expression](https://github.com/etiennetremel/PHP-Find-Date-in-String)

Also you can use `preg_match` function.